# Looping for events in actionscript 3, only get last number

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, flash, events

So I want to code faster by making array of all button that I have, and also make array of function which index numbers are connected to the array of each buttons.

For example, `buttons[0]`, handler events for hover is `button_over_funcs[0]` and for out is `button_out_funcs[0]`.

To make it clearer (since english is not my first language), take a look at my code:

```
var buttons:Array = [playbtn, tutorialbtn];
var button_over_funcs:Array = new Array();
var button_out_funcs:Array = new Array();

var i = 0;
for each(var j in buttons){
    j.buttonMode = true;

    button_over_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
        j.gotoAndPlay("hover");
    });
    button_out_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
        j.gotoAndPlay("out");
    });


    j.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, button_over_funcs[i]);
    j.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, button_out_funcs[i]);
    i++;
}
```

but the j will always refer to tutorialbtn, regardless which button I hover/out. I tried `for-in` as well

```
var buttons:Array = [playbtn, tutorialbtn];
var button_over_funcs:Array = new Array();
var button_out_funcs:Array = new Array();

for(var j in buttons){
    buttons[j].buttonMode = true;

    button_over_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
        buttons[j].gotoAndPlay("hover");
    });
    button_out_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
        buttons[j].gotoAndPlay("out");
    });


    buttons[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, button_over_funcs[j]);
    buttons[j].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, button_out_funcs[j]);
}
```

Both seems the same. It seems like actionscript always refers to the last value of j instead of assigning it. Do you have any idea on how to make this as I expected? Is it impossible to make this quicker and not assigning the button to do same exact stuff?

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in reinventing the wheel. Use [`SimpleButton`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html) and be done with it.

In general: a class is the way to go when you want to define behaviour that several objects have in common.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I just searched about it. However I'm in design school and we are only allowed to use button symbol, not code-generated button. And btw, I found a solution for my problem already. Thank you once more, I really appreciate your suggestion and will try it later.

Comment: @NathanielMannawi The button symbol **is** the `SimpleButton`! The button symbol takes care of all the functionality to change to the hover state. You are recreating functionality that's already there, just use it.

Comment: but I thought you have to programatically draw the button using `Sprite`? We are expected to draw it with hand and create symbol, and control it later. Is it possible to use `SimpleButton` on object that already drawn on screen using tools?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the way by myself. If you found same problem as me, you can take a look.

```
var buttons:Array = [playbtn, tutorialbtn];
var button_over_funcs:Array = new Array();
var button_out_funcs:Array = new Array();

function addOver(ob){
    button_over_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
            ob.gotoAndPlay("hover");
    });
}
function addOut(ob){
    button_out_funcs.push(function(e:MouseEvent){
            ob.gotoAndPlay("out");
    });
}
function addEvent(ob){
    addOver(ob);
    addOut(ob);
}
for each(var j in buttons){
    addEvent(j)
}


for(var i = 0; i<= buttons.length - 1; i++){
    buttons[i].buttonMode = true;
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, button_over_funcs[i]);
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, button_out_funcs[i]);
}
```